# How to get non-null sorted ascending data from Spark DataFrame?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I load the data into data frames where one of the columns is `zipCode` `(String type).`  I wonder how to get non-null values for that column in ascending order in Scala?  Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
scala> val df = Seq("2", "1", null).toDF("x")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [x: string]

scala> df.orderBy($"x".asc_nulls_last).show
+----+
|   x|
+----+
|   1|
|   2|
|null|
+----+
```